# GCP credentials json file that represents an anonymous user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, credentials

I have a library that calls GCS (Google Cloud Storage).
The library expects a JSON credentials file and fails if no file is provided.

For testing purposes is there a way to create a JSON credentials file that represents an anonymous user?

I have tried passing an empty JSON object, but that results in an error.

Note: the library in question is internal and as a workaround has been modified to instantiate a GCS client using JSON credentials or an anonymous client based on configuration. This solution is suboptimal since it introduces code that will only be used during testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For testing purposes is there a way to create a JSON credentials file
> that represents an anonymous user?

No.

The user (identity) is specified by an OAuth Token using the HTTP header **Authorization Bearer TOKEN**.

An anonymous request is one without the HTTP header **Authorization**.

Comment: I'm aware GCP uses OAuth2. Many authentication systems use an actual "anonymous user" system account to which anonymous requests are mapped. I was hoping there was a way to generate a token for such an account (assuming it even exists).
Is your answer from actual knowledge of the underlying system?

Comment: @EliAlgranti Note: You can create a service account with no IAM roles. That is still an identity but one with no RBAC permission. That identity can be used for Identity-based authorization (as in OIDC Identity Token). That should work with your library as the library cannot tell without making an IAM inquiry and that would require permission.